# Not sure how to update parent state from the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `CreateTesterModal` class which has a state of location. This class renders a form component that shows up inside this modal class like so:
`CreateTesterModal -> CreateTesterForm`

### [image: CreateTesterModal]

When user clicks on `Add` Location link then this new modal opens which contains the location form
`CreateTesterForm -> AddLocationModal -> AddLocationForm`

### [image: AddLocationModal]

My **question** now is how do I update my location state from the main modal (`CreateTesterModal`) based on what user will enter in the child component of `AddLocationForm`?

I am new to `react` and really need this logic to work without using `redux`. Can someone please help?

---

**CreateTesterModal:**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fields: {
        location: 'No Location Selected',
      }
    };
  }

  fieldChange(field, value) {
    this.setState(update(this.state, { fields: { [field]: { $set: value } } }));
  }

  updateLocation(newLocation) {
    this.setState({
      location: newLocation
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <div className={`modal-body ${styles['proj-modal-body']}`}>
          <CreateTesterCharacteristicForm
            fields={this.state.fields}
            onChange={this.fieldChange.bind(this)}
            onValid={() => handleSubmit(this.state.fields)}
            onInvalid={() => console.log('Error!')}
            updateLocation={this.updateLocation.bind(this)}
          />
        </div>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**CreateTesterForm:**

```
<form>
    <div id={styles.locationField} className={`form-group ${styles.formGroup} ${styles.projName}`}>
              <label htmlFor="inputEmail3" className="col-sm-2 control-label">Location:</label>
              <div className="location">
                <label className="radio-inline">
                  &nbsp;
                  <Link to="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addLocationModal">Add Locations</Link>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
    </form>
    <button
            className={`btn btn-primary text-white ${styles.saveBtn}`}
            onClick={e => {
              e.preventDefault();
              this.props.$submit(onValid, onInvalid);
            }}
          >
            Save
          </button>
<AddLocationModal />
```

**AddLocationModal:**

```
render() {
    return (
      <div id="newLocationModal">
        <AddLocationForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**AddLocationForm:**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      locations: [],
    };
  }
render() {
  return (
    <form id="modalForm" className="form-horizontal">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="location"
      />
      <div className={`modal-footer ${styles.modalFooter}`}>
        <button className={`btn btn-primary text-white ${styles.saveBtn}`}>
          Add More
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className={`btn btn-default ${styles.cancelBtn}`}
          data-dismiss="modal"
        >
          Finish
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: React has a unidirectional dataflow so if you need something to happen in the parent triggered by the child, one way to do this is by passing a function doing that as a prop to the child. Please post a minimal code reproducing what you have and how you tried to solve it.

Comment: @3Dos I just updated my post with code that I have

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can do this by passing a handler from the parent to the child

> **Attention :** Here the handler works fine with `this` because it has been defined as an arrow function. If using the class method syntax, don't forget to bind the `this` of the class to the method or `this` will reference the DOM element triggering the event (in this case, the `button`)

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = { location: null }

  updateLocation = location => {
    this.setState({ location })
  }

  render () {
    return <div><Child updateLocation={this.updateLocation} /></div>
  }
}

// Get the updateLocation function as a prop in your child component
const Child = props => {
  const { updateLocation } = props

  return <button onClick={() => updateLocation('someLocation')}>Some Location</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to define a function in the child component that calls another function in the parent component(as props) with the data you want to update.I don't have your code but it should be something like this:

```
//child component
  ...class
  update = (data) =>{
   this.props.Parentupdate(data)      
    }
  //Parentupdate is the function in the parent class that will be passed down as props to the child comp.

//Inside the parent component
   update = (data) =>{
    this.setState({data etc etc})
}
//When rendering the child component
  <Child Parentupdate={this.update}/>
//This is passing the parent function to the child as a prop.
```